# Not able to convert to Executable Jar File-Main class is not loading

Tags: junit, selenium-rc

I am doing Selenium Remote Control script in Eclipse IDE.

My Java code will be as follow:

```
package Com;
import Statements;
public class Main extends TestCase { 
    public static Selenium browser;
    int SmallDelay=5000;
    int BigDelay=10000;
    public void test_MailLogin() throws Exception { }

    public void patients() { }

    public void claims() { }
}
```

But I could not convert this into Executable Jar file.

Result:

On converting into Jar file I cant find Launch configuration.

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] blablabla)... 
you need a main function..